# Flask app works locally, but not on Heroku (Method not allowed)

Tags: python, heroku, flask

My python code works fine when I run it locally, but fails on Heroku when I hit the submit button on my form and I get the error: Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
import dill

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def main():
  return redirect('/index')

@app.route('/index',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    message = '  '
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html',output=message)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
      gender = request.form.get('sex')
      poverty = request.form.get('poverty')
      school = request.form.get('school')
      marital = request.form.get("marital")
      race = request.form.get("race")
      orient = request.form.get("orient")
      phys = request.form.get("phys")
      drinks = request.form.get("drinks")
      age = request.form.get("age")
      message = '  '
      output = get_risk([phys,orient,school,drinks,race,poverty,marital,gender,age])
      if output ==0:
        message = "Not At Risk"
      elif output == 1:
        message = "At Risk!"
      return render_template('index.html',output=message)

def get_risk(features):
  forest = dill.load(open('forest.pkd','rb'))
  return forest.predict(features)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Make sure your HTML has the `method="POST"` attribute on the form element and the `action` attribute specifies the correct route.

Answer (score 2):

"Method not allowed" in the browser is common and doesn't really tell you much- it's a way to hide the details of the error from users who shouldn't see your code or know about the details your app. Try heroku logs to get a more detailed report. I have been getting the same error even though the heroku logs say my app is running on heroku

Answer (score 0):

Seeing this 3 years and 8 months later. I had simply created the app first and tested the default page heroku creates but I was getting this Method Not Allowed. My issue was using the wrong link. The git.heroku.com/`yourapp`.git gives this error. But the `yourapp`.herokuapp.com/ link worked.  Again, this was just with the default page.

If you deployed your app and errors exist at the correct URL, you will probably be getting an Application Error page and as mentioned before, you need to utilize the heroku logs on their dashboard to resolve those.